# In Magento 2 can I have the product page title be different than the product name?

Tags: magento2

Is that configurable in admin or does it have to be done in the code base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meaning the meta title `<title>`, or the H1 tag?

The meta title is configurable in the admin panel, just like it always has been:

```
Admin > Products > Catalog > {edit product} > Search Engine Optimization > Meta Title
```

Changing the H1 tag content to something other than the product name would require modifying the product page template in your theme.

Comment: Meta title will show up on the tab in the browser and as the main line in a search result?

Comment: Meta title shows up in the browser tab and search engine (Google) results.